# Call UniVerse Command from Shell

Tags: shell, universe, u2

I have a UniVerse (Rocket U2) system, and want to be able to call certain UniVerse/TCL commands from a shell script. However whenever I run the `uv` binary it seems to stop the execution of the rest of the shell script.

For Example if I run:
`/u2/uv/bin/uv`

It starts a UniVerse session. The next line of the script (`RUNPY run_tests.py`) is meant to be executed in the TCL environment, but is never input to TCL. I have tried passing in string parameters to the `uv` binary to be executed, but doesn't appear to do anything.

**Is there a way to call UniVerse/TCL commands from a UNIX/Shell environment?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type this manually or put it into a shell script. I have not run into any issues with this paradigm, but your choice of shell could theoretically affect this. You certainly want to either be in the directory of the account you want execute it in or cd to it in the script.

```
/u2/uv/bin/uv <<start
RUNPY run_tests.py
start
```

Good Luck.

Comment: This works great, thanks! I was glad that my limitation was my BASH skills and not a UniVerse one.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to watch out for is if you have a LOGIN paragraph or something else that runs automatically to start your application (which is really common), then you need to find a way to bypass this for non-interactive users.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.databases.pick/B2hzuXq3X9A mentions

```
IF OCONV(@TTY,'MCU')='PHANTOM' THEN ABORT
```

In UD, I kick off scripts from unix as a phantom to a) capture the log output in PH and b) end the process if extra input is requested, rather than hanging around.  In UD that's

```
$echo "PHANTOM COUNT VOC" | udt
UniData Release 8.1  Build: (2008)
Current UniData home is /unidata/ud81/.
Current working directory is /usr/ud81/demo

:PHANTOM COUNT VOC
PHANTOM process 18743448 started.
COMO file is '_PH_/dsiroot45172_18743448'.
:
Critical abort condition found.

$cat _PH_/dsiroot45172_18743448
COUNT VOC
14670 record(s) counted.
PHANTOM process 18743448 has completed.
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. It wasn't my issue here, but good to know for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

[Van Amburg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008427/call-universe-command-from-shell/57011696#answer-57011453) is the most correct for handling multiple lines of input. The variant I used was instead of the `<<` command for multi-line strings I just added quotes around a single command (single and double quotes both work):

`/u2/uv/bin/uv "RUNPY run_tests.py"`